# Activity Recognition Pending intent Call Backs Never Get Fired

Tags: android, activity-recognition

In my application the activity recognition updates are directed to a IntentService through a pending Intent.I observed that **sometimes** the updates never get fired. But when phone is restarted the update start to fire.Have anybody come across this scenario?Is there some tuning that can be done ?

Comment: Have you use broadcast receiver??

Comment: Sorry,what exactly did you mean?I am registering for activityRecogntion Updates via a pending Intent that will start Intent service.Then in the Intentservice the result is then broadcasted locally in my application.Did you mean to say that i should use a Broadcast receiver instead of IntentService in the Pending Intent?But what good does that do?

Comment: I faced a similar issue myself. It seems to be a security issue in KitKat and possibly in older versions of android. have a look [here.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61850)

Comment: @Forsyth thanks - that link contained the solution for me on Nexus5/KitKat: using PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT rather than PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT got things working.